# Windows 8 Store In-App purchases

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I've been searching the internet for hours now and I still cannot resolve an issue I'm having with my `IAP`'s, I have 2 in app products and I have this in my code:

```
private async void RenderStoreItems()
    {
        picItems.Clear();

        try
        {

            ListingInformation li = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();

            foreach (string key in li.ProductListings.Keys)
            {
                ProductListing pListing = li.ProductListings[key];
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(key);

                string status = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[key].IsActive ? "Purchased" : pListing.FormattedPrice;

                string imageLink = string.Empty;

                picItems.Add(
                    new ProductItem
                    {
                        imgLink = key.Equals("AdvertBlocker") ? "/Assets/Purchases/NoAds.png" : "/Assets/Purchases/NoAds.png",
                        Name = pListing.Name,
                        Status = status,
                        key = key,

                    }
                );
            }

            pics.ItemsSource = picItems;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This is called upon `Page_Load` however on this line `ListingInformation li = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();` I receive an exception. I've searched everywhere as to why I'd receive such exception, here are the reasons:

1. I haven't added any IAP's
2. My ProductID is incorrect to the one specified on the dev center dashboard

However, I have done every single possible reason as to why it shouldn't be working but it still doesn't work?

I've also tried, rather than `CurrentApp` I've used `CurrentAppSimulator` it works but I receive invalid information, for example a name of a product would be "Spinner" but the received name would be "ProductName1"

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the `ProductID` or `PhoneProductID` in `Package.AppManifest` to the one MSFT provides you on DevCenter. That error mean's the API 404'd when trying to contact the store using the wrong `GUID`(a.k.a the one that Visual Studio provided you).